# Why does tesseract OCR recognition quality degrade when run on iOS device versus Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, tesseract

Simply put, I get near perfect text recognition by TesseractOCR when I run the code on the iPhone 6 simulator, but recognition degrades substantially when I run the same code on an actual iPhone 6. On the device, some of the degradation occurs near non-text artifacts (e.g., lines).  In another case, there is consistent single character recognition error for the same alphanumeric string. Some of the text is bold, some not.  There are several font sizes.

So my question is: Does anyone know why recognition quality is better on the simulator and what can I do if anything to improve recognition on the iPhone?

I have built a simple iOS test app that translates an image to text using TesseractOCRiOS. Eventually, the images will come from the device camera, but for now I just use a test image of an invoice formatted as a jpeg. The process looks something like the following:

```
jpeg->UIImage->NSData->UIImage->Tesseract
```

I'm assuming this process is lossless. The intermediate translation to NSData is part of the overall process because the device camera yields image data and the Photo Library stores image data—the use of a jpeg test image at this point makes the process look a little convoluted.

To install TesseractOCRiOS I followed the instructions on the [wiki](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS/wiki/Installation). I installed TesseractOCRiOS 4.0.0 using the following pod file.

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
workspace 'DocumentCaptureV2'
xcodeproj 'DocumentCaptureDemo/DocumentCaptureDemo.xcodeproj/'

target 'DocumentCaptureDemo' do
   pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', '4.0.0'
end

target 'DocumentCaptureDemoTests' do
   pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', '4.0.0'
end

target 'DocumentCaptureDemoUITests' do
   pod 'TesseractOCRiOS', '4.0.0'
end

post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
           config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
       end
   end
end
```

The post install bit was added to make it work on an iPhone 6 device. Absent this bit of pod file stuff (it took a some searching to find this bit of magic), the link fails when trying to run it on the device (can't use weak library and enable bitcode).

The code I use to recognize the text is below (basically the example code on the github). I did change the recognition time from 1 to 10 thinking that the iPhone might need more time. It didn't make a difference.

```
func updatePageText(page: Page, image: UIImage?) {
    if image != nil {
        // Create a new `G8RecognitionOperation` to perform the OCR asynchronously
        // It is assumed that there is a .traineddata file for the language pack
        // you want Tesseract to use in the "tessdata" folder in the root of the
        // project AND that the "tessdata" folder is a referenced folder and NOT
        // a symbolic group in your project
        let operation = G8RecognitionOperation(language: "eng")

        // Use the original Tesseract engine mode in performing the recognition
        // (see G8Constants.h) for other engine mode options
        operation.tesseract.engineMode = G8OCREngineMode.TesseractOnly;

        // Let Tesseract automatically segment the page into blocks of text
        // based on its analysis (see G8Constants.h) for other page segmentation
        // mode options
        operation.tesseract.pageSegmentationMode = G8PageSegmentationMode.AutoOnly;

        // Optionally limit the time Tesseract should spend performing the
        // recognition
        //operation.tesseract.maximumRecognitionTime = 10.0;

        // Set the delegate for the recognition to be this class
        // (see `progressImageRecognitionForTesseract` and
        // `shouldCancelImageRecognitionForTesseract` methods below)
        operation.delegate = self;

        // Optionally limit Tesseract's recognition to the following whitelist
        // and blacklist of characters
        //operation.tesseract.charWhitelist = @"01234";
        //operation.tesseract.charBlacklist = @"56789";

        // Set the image on which Tesseract should perform recognition
        operation.tesseract.image = image;

        // Optionally limit the region in the image on which Tesseract should
        // perform recognition to a rectangle
        //operation.tesseract.rect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 100, 100);

        // Specify the function block that should be executed when Tesseract
        // finishes performing recognition on the image

        operation.recognitionCompleteBlock = {(tesseract: G8Tesseract!)->Void in
            page.text = tesseract.recognizedText.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
            Page.save()
        }

        // Finally, add the recognition operation to the queue
        operationQueue.addOperation(operation);
    }

}
```

I am assuming that the UIImage I pass to updatePageText is complete (i.e., not still loading). I have looked at the thresholdedImage on the iPhone 6 and there is nothing odd that I can see. There's is virtually no documentation on tesseract configuration so I haven't really tried anything there.

Comment: If the native device/simulator runs the code faster, and the more 'iterations' of the algorithm is applied, it might explain the difference .. what happens if bumping up the time *excessively*, such that it is not a 'limit' on either device or emulator?

Comment: One of the first things I tried was increasing `tesseract.maximumRecognitionTime` from 1.0 to 10.0.  I have since then tried 100.0 (I am assuming this is seconds).  It does not appear to have any effect nor any noticeable impact on running time (seems to be instantaneous).  I am wondering if there are differences in the libraries available on the iPhone versus those available on my laptop that result in degraded performance.  Alternatively, could there be architecture dependent differences in the tesseract libraries that cause degradation.